# How do you setup a dropdown that shows the value but selects the key?

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have a defined name range that has values as follows:

```
+----------+------+
| BodyPart | Code |
+----------+------+
| Head     |    1 |
| Torso    |    2 |
| Abdomen  |    3 |
| Ankle    |    4 |
+----------+------+
```

Since the code are hard to remember, I'm trying to setup data validation to show the BodyParts in the dropdown, and when selected, show the code in the spreadsheet.

How is this accomplished?

Comment: @Scott Craner, how did you fix the formatting? I was looking for how to do this, and everywhere I saw just said copy paste from [senseful solutions](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) website.

Comment: for yours I just put 4 spaces in front of each line.

Comment: How about in the cell next to the drop-down list write `=vlookup(A1,sheet!List!$A$1:$B$4,2,0)` - This will show body part in drop-down and code next to. (formula assumes drop-down in A1 and table in sheet("list").Range("A1:B4")

Comment: @Scott Holtzman, good idea, but this doesn't work for us as the spreadsheet is used for data entry and the columns need to follow a pre-determined sequence. The spreadsheet is used during an automated import process and expects the data in a certain order. I'm trying to ensure the data is valid by providing the data entry clerk a view of the description, while selecting the code. And a product level change (a change to the import functionality) is out of the question.

Comment: does the cell result need to return to the code for everything has to work properly - or could it return `Code (Body Part) or Body Part (Code)` ... or could you just wipe out the extra column before importing?

Comment: How about `=MATCH(CellWithDropDown,RangeWithListOfValues,0)`

Comment: @Scott Holtzman, unfortunately, the cell result needs to contain the code. Any concatenation would require a product change in the application performing the import.

Comment: @xidgel, thanks for your reply. Where would this formula used?

Comment: There is a solution using VBA. Are you okay with that? The basics of it are 1) user selects body part from drop-down 2) once that is changed, the script grabs the body-part code, deletes the data validation from the cell and then enters the code. I can post if you want to try that.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman, absolutely! If the changes are contained in the spreadsheet, even if it's a macro or a VS script, then it's an approved change. We just want to avoid making a product change to the application which performs the import. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vba solution that will solve your issue (with links explaining how to do the various things in case you need them):

1. Place your table in a separate sheet in the file
2. [Define a Name](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html#NameBox) for the BodyPart column as `BodyPart` (set scope to Workbook Level)
3. Define a Name for the whole table (both columns) as `BodyPartCode` (set scope to Workbook Level)
4. Set the Data Validation for each cell to List with Source `=BodyPart`
5. Place the code below in the [`Worksheet Module`](http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html#Worksheet) of the sheet with the data.

The code below will run everytime a user changes a cell value on the sheet. If the changed cell is in the same column as the DropDown list, the code will lookup the body part code based on the body part entered, then remove the data validation from the cell, so that the code can be entered in the cell without breaking the validation for the body part drop down.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With Target

    If .Column = 6 Then 'assumes drop-downs listed in column F, change as needed

        Dim sPart As String, sCode As String
        sPart = .Value2
        sCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sPart, Range("BodyPartCode"), 2, 0)

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        .Validation.Delete

        .Value = sCode

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, although I'm running into Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. Looking up answers online right now.

Comment: Resolved. Thanks for your help. I had to change the Range("BodyPartCode") to Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BodyPartCode") and then it worked. I also removed the .validation.Delete .Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: glad you got it going @AlexScript!